# Catch django signal sent from celery task

Tags: django, celery, signals

Catch django signal sent from celery task. Is it possible? As far as I know they are running in different processes

```
@celery.task
def my_task():
    ...
    custom_signal.send()

@receiver(custom_signal)
def my_signal_handler():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take in mind that your async task must be @shared_task decorator. in order to be called from outside since it will not be attached to a concrete app instance. [Documentation @shared_task celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

**task.py**

```
@shared_task
def send_email(email):
    # Do logic for sending email or other task
```

**signal.py**

as you can see below this will only execute when post_save (After user executes save) for the model Contract in your case would be anyother model that its being executed.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Contract)
def inflation_signal(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        send_email.delay('mymail@example.com')
```

Comment: It looks like you don't  understand me. I mean sending signal from celery task to django, not otherwise

Comment: @timKa Did you ever find an answer that worked?  I looking for the same thing.